# How to find the extension of a file once it has been removed or changed?

Tags: forensics, file-types

Say you are given a file whose extension has been removed or changed (file.tar.gz --> file.blah). This file is decompressed and its contents are used by an application. But you don't have access to that application to know how. So how do you figure the file's extension to be able to decompress it for yourself? For example can you do that by inspecting the file with a hex editor?

Comment: Many files begin with [magic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_format#Magic_number) like 0xCAFEBABE in Java .class files, <?xml in XML, etc. Also, check this out: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures

Comment: Also, this might smell better on Superuser.

Comment: Is the compression aspect of the question valuable?  Or could the question be more clearly stated as "How to find the extension of a file once it has been removed or changed?"

Comment: Use the `file` command?

Answer (score 5):

Use the `file` command on the file?

Answer (score 1):

You can identify most common  file types by looking at their file headers in an hex editor (first block of bytes of the file), i.e. .exe files used by msdos systems use MZ at offset 0h, or a zip file has the [following header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_%28file_format%29#File_headers), etc.

I would do a search with, say, the first 8 bytes of the file.